# Help in understanding the notation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I am reading the paper in this link
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20327748/99-16.ps.pdf

Please help me in the notation used in page 5, $(M \vee \phi_n)\wedge M$

it is in line 2 of page 5.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be best to send the authors an email and ask them, since they are the only ones who knows by certain. Nevertheless, let me make a guess:

I think that
$$
u\wedge M=\min(u,M)
$$ 
and that 
$$
u\vee M=\max (u,M). 
$$
I'm not certain of what they want to do, but I *guess* that they are cutting the sequence $\phi_n$ off at the values $\pm M$ (in that case, I'd put the minus sign at a different place).

Comment: Downvoter, please explain! I'm trying to help...

Comment: thanks, I felt it is standard notation and I am ignorant. Now I can ask confidently to authors.

Comment: The $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are standard for some people. Good luck!